# Qlabel убирает пробелы при выводе

Tags: html, c++, qt, qt5.15

Выдаю таблицу в Qlabel. Для этого использую связку QLABEL - HTML. При выводе текста в ячейку убираются пробелы перед знаком равенства.В данном случаи перед знаком равно 2 пробела 'Ub  =' а показан только один пробел.

```
void Calibration3::outInfoTable()
{
QString str;

QString I     = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.current);
QString I1    = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.MeasCurrent1);
QString I2    = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.MeasCurrent1);
QString Imax  = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.MaxCharDischarCurent);
QString Ub    = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.voltAcumBat);
QString U36   = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.volt36V);
QString Unom  = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.NomVoltage);
QString Umax  = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.voltMax);
QString Umin  = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.voltMin);
QString Isol  = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.insulation);
QString T1    = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.temp1);
QString T2    = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.temp2);
QString f     = QString().asprintf("%05d", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.frequency);
QString S1k   = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.Sensor1_K);
QString S1b   = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.Sensor1_B);
QString S2k   = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.Sensor2_K);
QString S2b   = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.Sensor2_B);
QString UAk   = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.VBat_K);
QString UAb   = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.VBat_B);
QString U36k  = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.V36V_K);
QString U36b  = QString().asprintf("%3.2f", sysVar->memMapDevRx[246].chDs.V36V_B);


str.clear();
str = QString(
            " <H4><CENTER><font color='green'><b>Связь есть!<\b></CENTER></H4>"
            " <CENTER> <TABLE BORDER=0>"
            "%1 %2 %3 %4"
            " </TABLE> </CENTER>"
            )
          .arg(buildRow("I   ="    , I    ,    "I1  ="   ,  I1  ,  "I2=  "    , I2   , "PINK"    ))
          .arg(buildRow("Ub  ="    , Ub   ,    "U36 ="   ,  U36 ,  "Umax="    , Umax , "YELLOW"  ))
          .arg(buildRow("Unom="    , Unom ,    "Isol="   ,  Isol,  "T1=  "    , T1   , "#00f000" ))
          .arg(buildRow("f   ="    , f    ,    "     "   ,  " " ,  "     "    , " "  , "#00f000" ));

ui->label_3->clear();
ui->label_3->setText(str);
}

QString Calibration3::buildRow(QString txt1, QString value1, QString txt2, QString 
value2, QString txt3, QString value3, QString bgcolor)
{
 QString str= QString(
             " <TR BGCOLOR=%7>"
             " <TD>%1%2</TD><TD>%3%4</TD><TD>%5%6</TD>"
             " </TR>")
          
.arg(txt1).arg(value1).arg(txt2).arg(value2).arg(txt3).arg(value3).arg(bgcolor);
 return str;
}
```

[image: вот что получил]

[image: добавил]

Comment: Какие пробелы у вас убираются? Все пробелы, которые есть в коде, есть и в таблице.

Comment: Или вы имеете в виду несколько пробелов подряд? Это не Qlabel виноват, это по HTML так должно быть. Если нужно выровнять знаки равенства, разместите их в отдельном столбце.

Comment: А как можно добавить подряд пробелы в HTML?

Comment: Никак. Вообще выравнивать знаки равенства пробелами - плохая идея, так как на форме у вас шрифт не моноширинный. Лучше всего будет разместить знак равенства в отдельном столбце.

Comment: Я могу сделать шрифт моноширинный.

Comment: Для моноширинного шрифта можно использовать неразрывный пробел: `&nbsp;`

Comment: Добавил &nbsp; равно выравнялись. А как можно автомотизировать добавление &nbsp;?

Comment: Я не понимаю этого вопроса. Добавление обычных пробелов вы же не автоматизируете?

Comment: Если под "автоматизацией" подразумевается вычисление максимального количества знаков в названии параметра и добавление нужного количества неразрывных пробелов, то встроенных функций для этого нет. Нужно писать самому. Но если вы всё же разместите знак равенства в отдельном столбце, то делать этого не придется: всё выровняется автоматически.

Comment: Просто не надо использовать QLabel для таких вещей - тут самое место для `QTableWidget`, или `QTableView`, а QLabel он для относительно простых строк текста